# Make youtube play in background

Tags: applications, youtube

Is there any mechanism for playing youtube in background? When i am playing just audio songs from youtube, i need to play it as on background, since there is no video in it.

Answer (score 1):

Install **Xposed framework** (root required), and then **YouTube background playback module**. Reboot, then play any video you want, and just exit via home button, audio will continue to play.